# Hibernate QueryDsl Insert statement

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

In Querydsl 4 Hibernate there are HibernateDeleteClause,HibernateUpdateClause. What about
inserting new records? I've tried to use HibernateUpdateClause but it always generate 
an HQL update ==> SLQ update.

How can I insert a new record? Here there are my querydsl queries (delete + insert):

```
QUniDati uniDati = QUniDati.uniDati;
HibernateDeleteClause queryUniDatiDelete = uniDatiDao.delete(uniDati)
.where(uniDati.id.idDomanda.eq(idDomanda));
queryUniDatiDelete.execute();

QUniDati uniDati = new QUniDati(String.format("uniDati_%d",posizione));
HibernateUpdateClause queryUniDatiUpdate = uniDatiDao
.update(uniDati)
.set(uniDati.id.idDomanda, idDomanda)
.set(uniDati.id.pos, posizione++)
.set(uniDati.parametro, propName.toUpperCase())
.set(uniDati.valore, propVal.toString())
.where(uniDati.id.idDomanda.eq(idDomanda));
queryUniDatiUpdate.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Querydsl supports only the DML clauses JPQL supports: UPDATE and DELETE.

For inserts, use the Hibernate API directly.

Answer (score 0):

you are right! 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e2610
Just why jpql have no insert while HQL have insert?

Answer (score 0):

you can use querydsl SQLInsertClause

https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/querydsl-examples/src